# Finding built-in objects and functions in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

I'm trying to figure out what all is available by default in Node and more specifically, what V8 brings to the table (things like the JSON object) that aren't part of the standard javascript spec. The docs on the node site are fine for its bindings but after googling around for a bit, I'm not finding much on what extras V8 has. Anyone know of a good resource or two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When developing in the browser there are many wonderful built in JavaScript functions that we can’t use because certain browsers don’t implement them. As a result, most developers never use them. In Node, however we can assume that everyone has the same JavaScript implementation and as such can use these wonderful functions and not implement them over and over in our own libraries.
>
> The following is a list of some interesting api bits that aren’t considered safe to use in a web setting but are built in to node’s V8 engine.

[ECMA 5 Mozilla Features Implemented in V8](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/ECMA-5-Mozilla-Features-Implemented-in-V8)